# Is there any directed acyclic graph dataset (multiple graph instances with one label per graph)?

Tags: graph, dataset, graph-databases, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there any directed acyclic graph dataset?

For example, [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/) contains lots of graph dataset. But I cannot find any dataset that satisfies the following three criteria:

1. all graph being DAGs(Directed Acyclic Graph)
2. multiple graph instances(not a huge single graph)
3. labelled

Is there public available dataset that satisfies these criteria?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are looking for. Also add a language tag.

Comment: I edited the problem. Sry what do u mean by a language tag? I am quite new to posting questions on stack overflow. Thanks for helping!

Comment: By language tag I mean a programming language tag like [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)  or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), if relevant

Comment: Thanks. The dataset doesn't necessary have to be associated with any programming language.